# lexical analysis python

Tags: python, string, escaping, quotes, lexical-analysis

Recently I made the following observation:

```
>>> x= "\'"
>>> x
"'"
>>> y="'"
>>> y
"'"
>>> print x
'
>>> print y
'
```

Can anyone please explain why is it so. I am using python 2.7.x. I know well about escape sequences.

I want to do the following:
I have a string with single quotes in it and I have to enter it in a database so I need to replace the instance of single quote(') with a backslash followed by a single quote(\'). How can I achieve this.

Comment: What were you expecting instead, and why?

Comment: [Python's Lexical Analysis chapter](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) may be of assistance.

Comment: Oscar's answer explains what's going on here.  You might find raw strings interesting as well.  `>>> z = r"\'"`
`>>> z`
`"\\'"`

Comment: I have edited the question with few more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside a pair of `""`, you don't need to escape the `'` character. You can, of course, but as you've seen it's unnecessary and has no effect whatsoever.

It'd be necessary to escape if you were to write a `'` inside a pair of `''` or a `"` inside a pair of `""`:

```
x = '\''
y = "\""
```

**EDIT :**

Regarding the last part in the question, added after the edit:

> I have a string with single quotes in it and I have to enter it in a database so I need to replace the instance of single quote(') with a backslash followed by a single quote(\'). How can I achieve this

Any of the following will work, notice the use of [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) for avoiding the need to escape special characters:

```
v = "\\'"
w = '\\\''
x = r'\''
y = r"\'"

print v, w, x, y
> \' \' \' \'
```

Comment: I do not want to escape the  single quote I want to add a backslash to the string. I also tried replacing with backslash followed by backslash followed by single quote(\\') but it did not work.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam How did it fail to work? What does `print "\\'"` print?

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam I edited my answer, now it includes the solution to the problem indicated after the edit in your question. Please don't forget to accept this answer if it was useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for all help. Behavior I wanted to achieve was not possible because the string in which I was replacing was not a raw string. If you make a the string on which you are applying function replace then it works fine,